# Laravel Eloquent: Relationship - hasOneThrough

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship, has-one-through

I have three tables in my database:

1. inquiry
2. post
3. product

Columns in `inquiry` table:

1. id
2. message
3. post

Columns in `post` table:

1. id
2. title
3. content
4. product

Columns in `product` table:

1. id
2. name

I have an `Inquiry` model and I want to show the post title and product name with my inquiry.

I found that hasOneThrough can help me with this and so far I have tried this:

`Inquiry Model`

```
class Inquiry extends Model {
   use HasFactory;

   public function product() {
      return $this->hasOneThrough(Product::class, Post::class, 'product', 'id', 'post', 'product');
   }
}
```

`Post Model`

```
class Post extends Model {
   use HasFactory;

   public function product() {
      return $this->hasOne(Product::class, 'id', 'product');
   }
}
```

`Product Model`

```
class Product extends Model {
   use HasFactory;
}
```

I followed [this page](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through) from laravel documentation.

So far, this code is giving me `internal server error`. Can someone explain what is wrong with this code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi ! when you have internal server error, Laravel gives you tons of useful information in the log file. You can usually find it in `storage/logs/laravel.log` Can you edit your question to include the error log you get for this error ?